# How to create a violin plot (or boxplot) for ordinal values in R?

Tags: r, boxplot, violin-plot

I am trying to create a violin plot for a huge dataset. I got an ordinal scaled variable for age groups (10-19, 20-29, 30-39, 40-49, and so on and a nominal variable for - let's say - drug use (YES/NO), medication intake (YES/NO), alcohol intake (YES/NO), gaming > 6 hours per day (YES/NO).

My goal is to create a boxplot (with R) with Age Groups on the x-axis and the different items on the y-axis. The x-axis would look like: 10-19, 20-29, 30-39, 40-49 years old, while the y-axis is just a stacking of different items that are independent of each other.

Mainly, I am interested in how to connect the ordinal scaled variable "age groups" and one single dichotomized item "drug use". It is worth mentioning that I only want to focus on people that answered YES. Therefore I created a new subset.

My code looks like this:

```
drug_age <- (drug_data$age)      #drug data = people that answered YES
data$age <- as.factor(data$age)
ggplot2(drug_data,aes(x=age,y=drugs,fill=drugs))+
         geom_violin)
```

As you can tell, I am lost at this point. My variables are factorized but at this point I don't really care about code, but more about logic.
My goal is to create a graphic that shows that the frequency of druge use is more common among 20-29 years olds than 10-19 years olds, for instance.

You don't have to write code for me or anything, it would just be super helpful to give me some hints.

Thank you so much for your help!

- Gertie

Comment: Violin plots are useful for continuous data distributions.  You don't have that here, as far as I can tell.  Instead, you might consider making a barplot where one yes/no variable is on the y-axis and your age-groups are on the x-axis.  Then maybe use facets or the ggarrange package to show many of these types of plots with different yes/no variables together.

Comment: Thank you, I already did that. In a next step, I only want to consider age distribution across people that use drugs, i.e. I don't pay attention to participants that answered "No". I already created a subset of participants that answered YES, but I really don't know how to create a single violin/box plot for the distribution across age. My goal is to see on the graphic that e.g. 273 people are 10-19, 590 are 20-29.